# How to add a onselect for vuetify 3 combobox

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, vuetify.js

Hi How to add a onselect for vuetify 3 combobox?

```
<v-combobox
              v-model="values1"
              :items="uniq"
              class="flex-full-width mt-5"
              density="comfortable"
              placeholder="Suche..."
              append-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
              variant="outlined"
              no-filter
              @update:modelValue="toogle"
              @update:search="updateForCustomerSearch"
            />
```

When the dropdown appears and I click on the dropdown I want that a specific method is executed.
But only when I select from the dropdown.

Kind regards

Severin

Viewed the Documentation in order to find a onSelect Event.

Comment: You have to add a Template with items and you can define a new dropdown with onClick handlers

Comment: Why don't you use `@update:modelValue`?